# Kafka Streams - Access data from last instance of the topic

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

We  have a producer sending data periodically that is being processed using Kafka Streams. We need to find the difference between the data that the producer sends between two consecutive attempts. One option would be to store the data in a database to look back at the previous transmittal. I was wondering if there is a way to do this using the aggregate or reduce functions.
i.e. if the producer first sends
`[100,500,600,800]` first and then sends `[100,500,800]`, I need to be able to identify the missing element `[600]`.

Comment: You can use `aggregate()`: https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#aggregating